# how to assign an associative index to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to assign a index 'Father Name' to demo value but not able to do that ,please help me.

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Abc
    [last_name] => Xyz
    [address] => xyz
    [email] => abcxyz@domain.com
    [contact_no] => 1234567890
    [exam_id] => 4
    [candidate_id] => abc.xyz
    [password] => seXUEz1n7cRRY
    [martial_status] => S
    [children] => 0
    [birth_date] => 1988-11-24
    [remark] => xyz
    [] => demo
)
```

Comment: What is the index of `demo` in the original array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should generally do the trick:

$array['Father Name'] = 'demo';

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have that index `null` with demo value in it and `Null` will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".

```
$array["Father Name"] = $array[null];
unset($array[null]);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tY9QK6)**.

**Same as**

```
$array["Father Name"] = $array[''];
unset($array['']);
```

Comment: `$array[null]` has no sense (because this `null` as an index would be converted implicitly to empty string, `''`) `//not my dv`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find and replace the item, you can do

```
$array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'demo');
$index = array_search('demo', $array);

if ($index !== false) {
    $array['Father Name'] = $array[$index];
    unset($array[$index]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
array('Father Name'=>'demo');
```